# Make a countdown using TimePicker

Tags: android, countdown, timepicker

II am trying to shutdown the app in a selected hour using the timepicker. I have this code but it doesnt work yet. I press the button and the hour is selected, but it doesnt get power off.

```
   public class ContadorproActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
TimePicker timePicker;
Button contadorpro;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contadorpro);

    timePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
    timePicker.setIs24HourView(true);

}
public void onClick(View view) {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Hora seleccionada:" + timePicker.getCurrentHour() +
            ":" + timePicker.getCurrentMinute(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd:MMMM:yyyy HH:mm:ss ");
    int hour = timePicker.getCurrentHour();
    int minute = timePicker.getCurrentMinute();
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(ContadorproActivity.this, MyReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ContadorproActivity.this, 0, myIntent,0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}
```

And there is java.class:

```
   public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Run your stuff
    Toast.makeText(context, "OnReceive!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
}
```

}

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: how to introduce this: android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid()); to do in the selected hour?

Comment: same issue i have http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32585264/how-to-set-time-of-timepicker-to-countdowntimer

Answer (score 0):

Once you've got the specific time, you can use the AlarmManager service to fire an exact alarm (use the setExact() method) where you call for the shutdown to happen. You can read more about the AlarmManager here: [AlarmManager - setExact()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExact(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent))

Just keep in mind that you may need additional processing if you need for this countdown to continue even after a system reboot.

Comment: can you tell http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32585264/how-to-set-time-of-timepicker-to-countdowntimer

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AlarmManager` to schedule an alarm at desired date:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyReceiver.class);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent,0);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Implement a `BroadcastReceiver` to run your action:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Run your stuff
        Toast.makeText(context, "OnReceive!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

---

EDIT:

Remember to declare your `BroadcastReceiver` in Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="<com.package.app>.MyReceiver " />
```

Comment: I have edit implementing your code but it doesnt work yet, help pls

Comment: You need to calculate when to start properly, I posted a brief example. Start trying `alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 5000, alarmIntent);` and check if it starts in 5 seconds. Let me know about it.

Comment: ` AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);        
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 5000, pendingIntent);`  I have tried this and nothing..

Comment: Did you registered the receiver in Manifest? Check my edited answer.

Comment: Yes, I wrote this: <receiver android:name=".MyReceiver" android:process=":remote" />